# using npm to run code in folders in tutorial downloaded from github

Tags: npm

I'm new to `npm` and I can't understand how to run a tutorial I found on GitHub. I suspect it has something to do with my lack of knowledge of `npm`

The tutorial is this one: https://github.com/IrfanBaqui/react-router-v4-tutorial

I'm on Windows 7.

I first tried running serving the `index.html` pages inside each folder via `XAMPP`... however, that didn't work (I just get a blank page).

Next, I tried navigating inside a folder via the command prompt and running `npm start`... that didn't work either... (I do have `npm` and `node.js` globally installed)

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:1
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Documents\Downloads\Irfan Baqui react-router-v4-tutorial-m
ct_Components\server.js:2:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each sub folder you need to do

- `npm install` it will install every lib you need.
- `npm start` it will run the project

The server should be running. To access the site it should be `localhost:9000`

Answer (score 1):

Well @sheplu has already answered your question. I would just like to let you know why it is needed.

It is a `node project`. The guys whose code you are trying to run have used many of the dependencies for each lesson (each folder in his repository).

what `npm-install` does is, download and resolves all the dependencies used in the project specified in the file named `package.json`. So, whenever you see a file `package.json` it would be there specifying dependencies for `dev` or `prod` environment. 
So, run `npm-install` in the directory where you see `package.json` file.

There can be another file `bower.json` with the same purpose (listing the required dependencies). if you see `bower.json`, you should run `bower-install` in that case.

And finally the script to run the project. `npm start` in your case.

And the error you just posted is clearly saying that `some-module` not found or could not resolve or something like that. That is because, you've resolved the dependencies required, which you'll have to using `npm-install` or `bower-install` for `package.json` and `bower.json` respectively